# AjaxControlToolkit Modalpopup OkControlID -vs- asp:Button OnClick event

Tags: vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an AjaxControlToolkit ModalPopupExtender to allow the selection of files to be zipped and downloaded. The asp:Button within the asp:Panel that populates the modal popup, has an OnClick property that refers to a code behind sub. This works as expected until the OkControlID property is added to the asp:ModalPopupExtender to facilitate the closing of the popup... Then the OnClick is ignored...  Does anyone know how I can have the same asp:Button, within the popup, call a codebehind sub and close the popup as well?

```
asp:Panel ID="DownLoadForm" runat="server" CssClass="download-form">
    <div class="download-header">Files Available For Download</div>
    <ul>
        <li><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" checked="true" enabled="false"/> File 1</li>
        <li><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" /> File 2</li>
        <li><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" /> File 3</li>
        <li><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" /> File 4</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>
            <asp:Button ID="btnZipAndDownload" runat="server" Text="Zip And Download" OnClick="Download"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancelDownload" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        </li>
    </ul>

</asp:Panel>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupDownload" runat="server"
    PopupControlID="DownLoadForm"
    TargetControlID="btnDownloadFiles"
    CancelControlID="btnCancelDownload"
    OkControlID="btnZipAndDownload" >
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

The sub in the code behind is "Download"

```
Protected Sub Download(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim FileName As String = "~/Mock_Files.zip"
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Mock_Borrower_Files.zip")
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip"
        Response.WriteFile(FileName, False)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Foo
        Foo too
    End Try

    Response.End()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use OnClientClick property and force postback with the `__doPostBack` function call:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnZipAndDownload" runat="server" Text="Zip And Download" OnClick="Download"
    OnClientClick="__doPostBack(this.name, '')" />
```

Comment: YES!!!!!!! Yuriy, I just burned FIVE HOURS trying to do this very same thing, and finally I stumbled across your simple solution. Thank you SO much!